# List user defined functions in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently using the pySpark console to play around with Spark and I was wondering if there is a way to list all functions that were define by me?

Currently I am forced to scroll all the way up to the definition of the function which can be tedious if you have a lot of output to scroll over.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your workspace clean makes more sense but if you really need something like this you can filter variables in the current scope:

```py
[k for (k, v) in globals().items() if (
    callable(v) and  # function or callable object
    getattr(v, "__module__", None) == "__main__" and  # defined in __main__
    not k.startswith("_")  # not hidden
)]
```